# Time complexity of a custom sorting algorithm

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity, analysis-of-algorithms

I am working with a sort like a bubble sort but the difference is that it works both ways from left to right. Like,
consider an array: 27 9 43 12 5
After going from left to right: 9 27 12 5 43 (43 is in the right position)
After going from right to left: 5 9 27 12 43 (5 is in the right position)
and it goes on.
Now, I have to prove the worst-case time complexity is O(n^2) and also Omega(n^2) and then conclude that it's Theta(n^2) from the previous 2 conclusions.

What I have done is  I am trying to conclude that O(n^2) but I can't seem to prove Omega(n^2).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g*., [basic help on mathjax notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), [main meta site math tutorial](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68388/there-should-be-universal-latex-mathjax-guide-for-sites-supporting-it/70559#70559), and [equation editing how-to](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto).

Comment: This sorting algorithm has several common names: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocktail_shaker_sort

Comment: Thank you so much @EricTowers for your help.